# calculating time difference in percentage for progress bar in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a progress bar that shows percentages based on the calculation. Im seeing an issue if the start date is today and the expiry is set for tomorrow, the percentage goes past 100% which is not correct. My code is below and please check and review. Any feedback will be appreciated. Thank you.

```
   export default function TrackBar({ storageDate, expiryDate }) {

  // function to convert timestamp to epoch
  function epoch(date) {
    return Date.parse(date)
  }
      // storage timestamp into epoch
  const storageTimestamp = epoch(storageDate)

  // expiry timestamp into epoch
  const expiryTimestamp = epoch(expiryDate)

  // current timestamp into epoch
  const dateToday = new Date()
  const todayTimestamp = epoch(dateToday)

  const progress = Math.floor((todayTimestamp - storageTimestamp)/(expiryTimestamp - storageTimestamp)* 100)
  console.log(progress)

  let color = ("#CF5C5C");

  if (progress <= 25) {
    color = ("#158463");
  } else if (progress <= 50) {
    color = ("#158463")
  } else if (progress <= 75) {
    color = ("#FD9345")
  } else if (progress <= 100) {
    color = ("#CF5C5C")
  }

  const progressStyles = {
    width: `${progress}%`,
    backgroundColor: `${color}`,
  };
  
if (!progress){
  return (
  <h1>Loading......</h1>
  )
}

  return (
    <>
      <div className="trackBar">
        <div className="trackBar__inner" style={progressStyles}></div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Can you please give a sample of the exact `storageDate` and `expiryDate` ? The answer posted so far is right in that you should code for 100+ situation, but you're also correct in that the case you mentioned shouldn't lead to that situation. (But also, maybe you should separate out below 0 as "not started" or something as well...)

Comment: For example the storageDate for an item is 2022-10-03 and expiryDate is 2022-10-04 based on the code that I posted above the progress bar goes past 100% and the item hasn't expired yet. I console log to see the progress it shows it shows over 100%. Im not quite sure I understand that well (But also, maybe you should separate out below 0 as "not started" or something as well...). Thank you for taking your time.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm unable to reproduce the error -  I just get 12%...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you did not handle the condition when the progress over 100. It is absolutely possible that `todayTimestamp` gets larger than `expiryTimestamp` only if time goes by. You need to add else if statement when progress goes beyond 100.

```
  } else if (progress <= 100) {
      color = ("#CF5C5C")
  } else {
      // progress larger than 100
      // your logic goes here        
  }
```

Else, you can render different jsx when `progress` is above 100.

```
if (progress > 100) {
    return <div> done </div>
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide me with a solution. I tried that method but rendering different jsx removes the progress bar which I don’t want to remove. Also, if storageDate is today and expiryDate is set for tomorrow I'm not able to understand how product is expired and progress goes past 100%. Thank you again 

Comment: @user19662721 You can edit the JSX as you like. Just include your progress bar inside `if (progress > 100)` block.

Also I do not produce the progress goes beyond 100 in the case you wrote in the comment.

Today is `Mon Oct 03 2022` and If I call the function like the following:
`trackBar({storageDate: new Date('2022-10-03'), expiryDate: new Date('2022-10-04')})`
It shows me 37 or something. I presume there might be a mistake in your input values.